# PHP open_basedir - to return value?

Tags: php, return, open-basedir

I want to return the value of open_basedir in a php script.. how can I do it?
If value is blank it should echo that is blank..

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[**`open_basedir`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) is a setting that's configured in `php.ini`

So, you can get its current value with [**`ini_get`**](https://www.php.net/ini_get) :

```
echo ini_get('open_basedir');
```

For example, if `open_basedir` is defined this way in my `php.ini` file :

```
open_basedir = /data/www:/var/www:/home/squale/developpement/tests
```

Then, the following portion of code :

```
var_dump(ini_get('open_basedir'));
```

Gets me this output :

```
string '/data/www:/var/www:/home/squale/developpement/tests' (length=51)
```